# LabelledGenerid.Aux implicit not available when using generic type in function body

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying this and it works:

```
`
    case class Foo(name: String)
```

`class Morphic(map: Map[String, Any]) {

  def add(k: String, v: Any) = {
    new Morphic((map + (k -> v)))
  }

  def to[T](): T = {
    def toClass[A]: ToCase[A] = new ToCase[A] // This is class to convert from Map to case class
    val res = toClass[Foo].from(map).get // <-- problem is here - cannot use T
    res.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}

object testApp extends App {
  var m = new Morphic(Map[String, Any]())
  var m1 = m.add("name", "john")
  println(m1.to[Foo])
}`

I should use T instead of Foo in `val res = toClass[T].from(map).get` but it doesn't compile saying implicit is missing

`toClass[T].from` is a function creating a given type of case class from Map

How do I make that implicit (and possibly others on which .from relies) available?

I tried `def to[T, H <: HList]()(implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, H]) = ...` but then I need to specify both types when calling the .to and I can't figure out what to specify for H

Thanks

Comment: Write your `ToCase`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `toClass[Foo].from(map)` is of type `Foo`. 
Where is `.get` in `toClass[Foo].from(map).get` from? Do you have `.get` in `Foo`?

Comment: Ah, maybe, it's not `Foo` but `Option[Foo]`.

Comment: Yes, .from returns an Option[Foo]. I spent few more hours on this and still no progress, I'm surely missing something fundamental here. Looks like implicits are lost if the case class type is defined in the function caller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform a `Map` into `HList`, and then the `HList` into `T`:

```
import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil, LabelledGeneric, Witness}
import shapeless.labelled._

case class Foo(name: String)

trait MapToHList[L <: HList] {
  def apply(map: Map[String, Any]): Option[L]
}
object MapToHList {
  implicit object hNilMapToHList extends MapToHList[HNil] {
    override def apply(map: Map[String, Any]): Option[HNil] = Some(HNil)
  }

  implicit def hConsMapToHList[K <: Symbol, V, T <: HList](implicit
                                                           mapToHList: MapToHList[T],
                                                           witness: Witness.Aux[K]
                                                          ): MapToHList[FieldType[K, V] :: T] =
    new MapToHList[FieldType[K, V] :: T] {
      override def apply(map: Map[String, Any]): Option[FieldType[K, V] :: T] = {
        val str = witness.value.toString.tail
        for {
          v <- map.get(str)
          t <- mapToHList(map)
        } yield field[K](v.asInstanceOf[V]) :: t
      }
    }
}

trait ToCase[A] {
  def from(map: Map[String, Any]): Option[A]
}
object ToCase {
  implicit def mkToCase[A, L <: HList](implicit
                                       gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, L],
                                       mapToHList: MapToHList[L]
                                      ): ToCase[A] =
    new ToCase[A] {
      override def from(map: Map[String, Any]): Option[A] = mapToHList(map).map(gen.from)
    }
}


class Morphic(map: Map[String, Any]) {

  def add(k: String, v: Any) = {
    new Morphic((map + (k -> v)))
  }

  def to[T](implicit toCase: ToCase[T]): T = toCase.from(map).get

}

object testApp extends App {
  var m = new Morphic(Map[String, Any]())
  var m1 = m.add("name", "john")
  println(m1.to[Foo]) // Foo(john)
}
```

> I tried 
>   `def to[T, H <: HList]()(implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, H]) ...`
>   but then I need to specify both types when calling the .to
>   and I can't figure out what to specify for H

You can call it as `` m1.to[Foo, FieldType[Witness.`'name`.T, String] :: HNil]() `` or `` m1.to[Foo, Record.`'name -> String`.T]() ``.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. My .from code was similar to yours but what was missing is the whole implicit wrapper. I still don't fully get how that works -means my poor understanding of the whole implicit thing, I will now make sure I fully get it :)

Comment: @r3stle55 Good luck. If you're satisfied with the answer you can _accept_ it.